# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know we can apply the L'Hospital's rule repeatedly $k$ times but $3^{\sqrt{n}}$ becomes unwieldy while taking derivative $k$ times. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: take the logarithm of the limit and evaluate that, then exponentiate it to get back the original limit

Comment: @Bertrand Einstein IV Is it possible to show a brief sketch of the steps. Thanks.

Comment: If you're assuming that $k$ is a positive integer you could proceed by induction on $k$. It appears that the induction step will only require one application of L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: How do I prove for the base case where k = 1? The result is still indeterminate.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}=\lim_{m \longrightarrow \infty}\frac{m^2}{3^m}$ by taking $m=\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Is $k>0$ given?

Comment: K is an integer >=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $\sqrt n$ throws a monkey wrench in taking derivatives of the denominator.  The chain rule will lead to products and the derivatives get longer and more complex.  But we replace  $m = \sqrt n$ then

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^k}{3^{\sqrt n}} = \lim\limits_{\sqrt n\to \infty} \frac {m^{2k}}{3^m}=\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \frac {m^{2k}}{3^m}$.

That stops the denominator's derivative from "spreading".  $(3^m)' = (\ln 3) 3^m$ and so the $2k$ derivative of $3^m$ is $(\ln 3)^{2k} 3^m$.

And the $2k$th derivative of $n^{2k} = (2k)!$, a constant. (Clear? Yes?  first derivative is $2k m^{2k-1}$ and second is $2k(2k-1)m^{2k-2}$ and induction....?)

So

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac {n^k}{3^{\sqrt n}} = \lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \frac {m^{2k}}{3^m}=\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \frac {(2k)!}{(\ln 3)^{2k} 3^m} = 0$

......

I suppose it is mildly interesting that if $\lim \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is in indeterminate form that l'hopitals rule not only states $\lim \frac {f(x)}{x} = \frac {\frac {df(x)}{dx}}{\frac {dg(x)}{dx}}$ but $\lim \frac {f(x)}{x} = \frac {\frac {df(x)}{dy}}{\frac {dg(x)}{dy}}$ for any $y$ dependent on $x$.....  which is really obvious and unsurprising if we care to think about it... which I'm not sure I ever had.....

Comment: No.  If $m=\sqrt n$ then $m^k$ is..... Jeebus!......  Maybe I should be tested for a brain tumor.  .... $n^k = (\sqrt n)^{2k} = m^k$.  And as $2k$ *is* always an integer there goes the lemur wrench... pity.  I thought the phrase "lemur wrench" was really funny.

Comment: Does $e$ stand for $3$?

Comment: What $e$? and .... Ah, jeez.......  No, it doesn't *stand* for $3$.  It is a typo *of* $3$..... jeesh......

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume

$$f(x) = \frac{x^k}{3^\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\implies f'(x) = \frac{3^\sqrt{x}kx^{k-1} - 3^\sqrt{x} \ln 3 \frac{1}{2\sqrt x} x^k}{3^{2\sqrt x}}$$

Examining critical points

$$kx^{k-1} = x^k \ln 3 \frac{1}{2\sqrt x} \implies x^* = \left(\frac{2k}{\ln 3}\right)^2$$

Now, we can verify that for this function, and for $k>0$

$$f'(x) \begin{cases}>0 & x<x^* \\ =0  & x = x^* \\ <0  & x> x^*\end{cases}$$

Using the monotone convergence theorem - this means that the limit exists. and must be zero

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "non-L'Hospital" way using $e^t =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m!} > \frac{t^m}{m!}$ for $t>0$.

Hence,

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{n^k}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}
& = & \frac{n^k}{e^{\sqrt n \ln 3}} \\
& < & \frac{n^k}{\frac{\left(\sqrt n \ln 3\right)^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!}} \\
& = & \underbrace{\frac{(2k+2)!}{\ln^{2k+2}3}}_{=C_k}\cdot \frac{n^k}{n^{k+1}}\\
& = & C_k\cdot\frac 1n \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

A different method:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k}{3^\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\frac{n^k}{3^\sqrt n}\right)\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^k}{3^\frac n2}\right)\right)$$

We can try to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^k}{3^\frac n2}\right)$ and plug the result back in.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^k}{3^\frac n2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}k\ln n-\frac n2\ln3=\lim_{n\to\infty}k\ln n-\frac{\ln3}2 n$$

Note that the derivative of $k\ln n-\frac{\ln3}2 n$ with respect to $n$ is $\frac kn-\frac{\ln 3}2$. As the derivative approaches $-\frac{\ln 3}2$ as $n$ tends to infinity, this implies the function will decrease without bound, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}k\ln n-\frac{\ln3}2 n=-\infty$.

Plugging this back:

$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^k}{3^\frac n2}\right)\right)=\exp(-\infty)=0$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: a single application of l'Hospital's Rule shows that when $b>1$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{b^x}=0$. (This can be shown easily without l'Hospital as well.)

Now using $a_n=\frac{n^k}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$, consider

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2k]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt[2k]{3}^{\sqrt{n}}}
=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\left(\sqrt[2k]{3}\right)^{x}}=0
$$

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2k]{a_n}=0$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.